# ElasticSearch - Simultaneous (case sensitive) Term and (case insensitive) Match search on same property

Tags: elasticsearch, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

How can one search trough the same property with both a case-sensitive Term query and a case insensitive Match query?

We have a Tags property that for several reasons we need to make case-sensitive. So we would like to search trough in this manner using relevance boosting to put the exact Term matches at the top while the potentially less relevant results with different casing lower in the results.

I know that the `lowercase` filter for index analysis allows for case-insensitive searching using Match queries, but as I mentioned we need to keep the Tags case-sensitive.

For now we use a `keyword` analyzer without `lowercase` filter on the tags to provide exact Term matches that are case-sensitive. Adding a Match query to that is useless because it is comparing against cased tokens.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think "term" query is sensitive and "match" insensitive

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that index analyzing is either one or the other (at least to my knowledge) so you either keep original casing when indexing and can't match different casing or lose casing when indexing and you can't differentiate casing and compare to the original (for boosting purposes)